# Infragistics Ultragrid - cannot override filter row apperance

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

1) Create a new a grid, enable filtering.

```
grid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowFiltering = DefaultableBoolean.True;
grid.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIType = FilterUIType.FilterRow;
```

2) Change the backcolor of the filter row, filter cell, and filter row active.

```
grid.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterRowAppearanceActive.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
grid.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterCellAppearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
grid.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterRowAppearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
```

3) Filter row backcolor remains unchanged. [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Mcb.png)

I've also tried disabling app styling, and disabling OS Themes.

```
this.UseAppStyling = false;
this.UseOsThemes = DefaultableBoolean.False;
```

I've also tried copying these changes to the grid_InitializeLayout() event.

I've also tried using a manually defined schema instead of binding to a datasource.

In general it seems that a majority of Infragistics appearance settings do nothing.

Some do work - for example, fixed row background color does change the color.

As seen here: http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/WinGrid_Specify_Fixed_Columns.html

So it's not as if all appearance overrides are being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This cell is in edit mode. You may try to set [EditCellAppearance](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridOverride~EditCellAppearance.html)